# Image crop error in some device

Tags: android, image, crop

I have an error when cropping an image from the Gallery.
When I crop the image with a **Moto G3** it works.
When I crop the same image with a **LG G4** it does not work, the application closes and does not produce any error.

If with the **LG G4** I trim the image and make it very small it works correctly.
What's wrong?

```
public Intent cropImage(Uri picUri) {
    Intent cropApps = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    cropApps.setType("image/*");
    List<ResolveInfo> list = getContext().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(cropApps, 0);
    int size = list.size();
    if (size == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Can not find image crop app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Recortar imagen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);
        Intent cropIntent = new Intent();
        cropIntent.setClassName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name);
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");

        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 1080);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 1920);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        return cropIntent;
    }
    return null;
}
```